# Enrich jest test failure with additional information

Tags: typescript, jestjs

Our jest tests are failing with some cryptic error when you miss to specify a mock. E.g. a missing mock for the router would in general fail with `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'resolve')` etc. I would like to support other developers in catching some specific errors and translate them to a hint to the solutions.

The current situation just let to huge test fixtures/mock-lists that are just not needed for a specific test, only because it's easier to copy everything instead of writing a test from scratch.

I tried to replace `it()`, without success. Most likely due my missing javascript/typescript knowledge. I also tried a custom environment and `handleTestEvent()`, but I guess this will only help me in log some hints, instead of wrapping the error itself. Adding a wrapping function around the `fn?: ProvidesCallback` of `it()` with a `try-catch-block` is pretty close, but I would like to have a global automatic solution.

Unfortunately I'm still thinking in my Java/JUnit-mindset. How to address my issue from a javascript/typescript/jest point of view?

Comment: Please give a [mre] rather than a description, _"without success"_ gives is very little to go on.

Comment: @jonrsharpe So replacing it() is the the most reasonable approach?

Answer (score 0):

I will go with typescript the snippet below in `setupFilesAfterEnv` file:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any,@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access
(global as any).it = function (original: jest.It) {
  const hintingIt = function (name: string, fn: () => Promise<unknown>, timeout?: number): void {

    original(name, async() => {
      try {
        return await fn();
      } catch (e) {
        if (e instanceof Error) {
          if (e.message == 'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading \'resolve\')') {
            e.message = '[Hint: Most likely you missed a mockUseRouter() call]\n' + e.message;
          }
        }
        throw e;
      }
    }, timeout);

  };
  hintingIt.concurrent = original.concurrent;
  hintingIt.each = original.each;
  hintingIt.only = original.only;
  hintingIt.skip = original.skip;
  hintingIt.todo = original.todo;
  return hintingIt;
}(global.it);
```